# How to calculate device translation from accelerometer values?

Tags: react-native, augmented-reality, accelerometer

I've been working on a react based camera application which records a video along with its translation motion for each frame. But react does not have a lot of libraries supporting AR, and the only library we found called Viro is not maintained. I wanted to avoid using these libraries and directly get the translation values from the accelerometer sensor values.
How do I go about doing that.

I had done a bit of googling and found that we could double integrate the acceleration wrt time to get the displacement, but also it has an issue where the noise will accumulate and make the displacement unusable.

So what is the actual method of getting it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you mean to use gyroscope data? what good is the translation gonna do you? were you really hoping to achieve sub-meter positioning accuracy on a smartphone without advanced local positioning systems, or the full use of an existing AR toolkit?

Comment: You are talking about dead reckoning. And it is very difficult w/only COTS IMUs. I can provide an answer instead of just a comment.  But the above statement is the TL;DR version. The only way out of this ... can you constrain your problem statement better (i.e. dead reckoning w/foot-falls or w/car-turn-and-rotation information)? Or maybe you only care about the (more manageable) frame to frame error and don't care about the over all (accumulated) error.

Comment: Actually, why aren't you considering using SLAM: Simultaneous Localization and Mapping?

Comment: (SLAM = SfM = AR, basically)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz
Sorry for the lack of details.
I'm working on a photogrammetry based application using an opensource software called colmap. Even though colmap can generate 3d models of the objects using camera, it requires camera translation values to scale the model. Camera app should just record the video and everything else will be done on server. This has to be done on react as well. Since react doesn't seem to have any libraries to obtain translations, I'm looking into other options.